# perl remove leading @ and = on a line

Tags: perl

I am new to perl scripting and I would like to remove some characters that can be at a beginning of a line. The characters I would like to remove are @ and/or =

Here is a file example :

```
@word <= Remove @
=word <= Remove =
@=word <= Remove @ AND =
=@word <= Remove = AND @
=@==@=@=@@word <= Remove all the = and @
```

At the moment, I use `substr($line, 0, 1, " ") if "@" eq substr($line, 0, 1);` but it only removes the first `@`. How can I edit this line so it removes all the leading `@` and `=` ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Doing that with a `substr` is a lot of overhead. Just use a regular expression substitution with [`s///`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/s.html).

```
while (my $line = <DATA>) {
    $line =~ s/^[@=]+//;
    print $line;
}

__DATA__
@word <= Remove @
=word <= Remove =
@=word <= Remove @ AND =
=@word <= Remove = AND @
=@==@=@=@@word <= Remove all the = and @
```

The pattern here is `/^[@=]+/`, which means _the beginning of the string, and then one or more of either `@` or `=`. You can use [regex101.com for a more detailed explanation](https://regex101.com/r/sKcJp5/1) of the pattern. It removes them, like your question said.

The output is:

```
word <= Remove @
word <= Remove =
word <= Remove @ AND =
word <= Remove = AND @
word <= Remove all the = and @
```

---

If you want to instead replace with spaces like your code did, you need to do something more complicated.

```
s/^([@=]+)/" "x length $1/e;
```

This solution [suggested by Tanktalus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43638092/perl-remove-leading-and-on-a-line/43638184?noredirect=1#comment74327650_43638184) makes use of the `/e` modifier, which lets you place Perl code in the substitution part of the `s///`. [The `x` operator](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Multiplicative-Operators) repeats a string *n* times. We use it to replace the whole amount of `@` and `=` at once (note the `+`) with the empty string repeated as many times as the captured string had characters.

If you prefer a solution without the `/e` modifier, keep reading.

```
1 while $line =~ s/^(\s*)[@=]/$1 /;
```

We capture `()` zero or more whitespace `\s`, and also match exactly one of either `@` or `=`, all anchored to the beginning of the string `^`. Then we replace that with the capture `$1` from the `()`, and a blank.

We run this substitution as the condition for a `while` loop, because we want it to reset the position of the regex engine after every try, as the beginning of the string has changed. The `1 while` [*post-fix* syntax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Postfix_(software)) is just a short way of writing:

```
while ( $line =~ s/^(\s*)[@=]/$1 / ) {
   # do nothing
}
```

The output of the code, run with the same program as above, is:

```
 word <= Remove @
 word <= Remove =
  word <= Remove @ AND =
  word <= Remove = AND @
          word <= Remove all the = and @
```

To see why this is doing what it's doing, try this:

```
while (my $line = <DATA>) {
    print $line;
    print $line while $line =~ s/^(\s*)[@=]/$1 /;
}
```

You'll see how it's starting over with every iteration of that `1 while ...` loop.

```
@word <= Remove @
 word <= Remove @
=word <= Remove =
 word <= Remove =
@=word <= Remove @ AND =
 =word <= Remove @ AND =
  word <= Remove @ AND =
=@word <= Remove = AND @
 @word <= Remove = AND @
  word <= Remove = AND @
=@==@=@=@@word <= Remove all the = and @
 @==@=@=@@word <= Remove all the = and @
  ==@=@=@@word <= Remove all the = and @
   =@=@=@@word <= Remove all the = and @
    @=@=@@word <= Remove all the = and @
     =@=@@word <= Remove all the = and @
      @=@@word <= Remove all the = and @
       =@@word <= Remove all the = and @
        @@word <= Remove all the = and @
         @word <= Remove all the = and @
          word <= Remove all the = and @
```

Comment: `s/^([@=]+)/" "x length $1/e` gets the spaces and avoids the while :)

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by substituting lines starting (`^`) with a `@` or `=` (`[@=]`):

```
perl -lane 's/^[@=]//g; print ' file.txt
```